# How to use Server certificate before its validity starts

Tags: .net, ssl, iis, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a SSL site hosted in IIS, with server certificate validity from 01/11/2019.
But due to business constraints my client machine has date of June 2019.
Because of which i get

> Unable to make a private connection to servername because the date and time (Monday, June 8, 2019 15:42:14) set on the computer are incorrect. NET :: ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

But on my local machine the date is set to current date and i am not getting the above error.
There are two options :

1. Recreate the server certificate with Valid from date prior to client date
2. Change the client date to current date.

Its not possible to implement any of the above options.
Is there any other option to bypass this error.I googled and could not find a feasible solution.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a third option, as that's how SSL/TLS is designed.

Comment: You should definitively do both 1 and 2. Messing with dates is not a good idea. And any properly compliant TLS stack with refuse certificates not yet valid or already expired.

Comment: "But due to business constraints my client machine has date of June 2019." These business constraints are certainly the core of the problem so instead of trying to circumvent then, spend your energy into fixing those insane constraints.

Comment: Try to import the server certificate in your system truststore as Trusted Root. This is what is usually done to accept self-signed or expired certificates

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your browser, but it is possible to ignore all certificate errors. For example, in Chrome, you can use the `--ignore-certificate-errors` command-line switch:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors
```

(change that to match wherever `chrome.exe` is on your computer)

However, **that disables all certificate validation**, not just dates. So if the certificate is issued by a non-trusted authority, it will still let it through. That will make man-in-the-middle attacks possible.

*Edit:* There is also a way to only ignore certificate errors for only specific certificates: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/188059

I'm curious to know what business requirement would require a date freeze.